# Reports of NiftyPlayer playing MP3s at double speed in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, mp3

i've recently recoded a website to use NiftyPlayer as an embedded MP3 player.

You can see a page here -> http://www.piccadillyrecords.com/shop/catalogue.php?genre=0

I've had reports from a few people that certain MP3s are playing through twice as fast on IE. This seems to be at random, I can't reproduce the effect.

Has anybody else come across this behaviour, any idea how to diagnose it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It generally has to do with the encoding of the mp3. I think the safest type of mp3s are Constant Bit Rate - CBR, rather than Variable Bit Rate - VBR because the variable bit rate require constant changing of the read speed. This can often lead to doublespeed vocals in different versions of flash.